# How to resize custom markers depending on zoom level in GMap.NET?

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I'm creating *GMap.NET* app and added some custom markers on it. Is it possible to make them scale depending on the zoom level of the map?

[image: Map]

Comment: **Is it possible to make them scale depending on the zoom level of the map ?** Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a custom GMapMarker and use the zoom level in the OnRender() to scale the image. Each zoom level has a different ratio but luckily for you, I have mesured them all. Not sure if the ratio changes with different map providers?

You can set the x/y scale and heading using a seperate thread and it will update in real time.

The "defaultZoomLevel" will set the zoom level at which the image has a 1:1 ratio. I have only tried the value 16, not sure it will work for other values you may need to calculate all the ratios for each value or extract the curve from the data and use that to scale the ratio.

Use this to set the zoom level when it changes:

```
private void Gmap_OnMapZoomChanged()
{
    //trackBar_Zoom.Value = (int)Gmap.Zoom;
    //label_Zoom.Text = "Zoom: " + trackBar_Zoom.Value.ToString();
    SelectedOverlay?.SetZoomLevel(Gmap.Zoom);
}
```

Use it like:

```
SelectedOverlay = new GMapMarkerImageOverlay(Gmap.Position, 0, 1, 1, Gmap.Zoom, Resources.GreySquare);          
Overlay_ImageOverlays.Markers.Add(SelectedOverlay);
```

And this is the MapMarker:

```
public class GMapMarkerImageOverlay : GMapMarker
{
    private readonly double deg2rad = 3.14159265 / 180.0;
    private readonly double rad2deg = 180 / 3.14159265;
    private readonly float defaultZoomLevel = 16;
    private float zoomRatio = 1f;

    private float heading = 0;
    private double zoom = 0;
    private float scaleX = 0;
    private float scaleY = 0;

    private Bitmap overlayImage;

    private void SetZoomRatio()
    {
        if (zoom < 12) 
        {
            zoomRatio = 0.045f;
        }
        else if (zoom == 12)
        {
            zoomRatio = 0.08f;
        }
        else if (zoom == 13)
        {
            zoomRatio = 0.155f;
        }
        else if (zoom == 14)
        {
            zoomRatio = 0.285f;
        }
        else if (zoom == 15)
        {
            zoomRatio = 0.53f;
        }
        else if (zoom == 16)
        {
            zoomRatio = 1f;
        }
        else if (zoom == 17)
        {
            zoomRatio = 1.88f;
        }
        else if (zoom == 18)
        {
            zoomRatio = 3.55f;
        }
        else if (zoom == 19)
        {
            zoomRatio = 6.75f;
        }
        else if (zoom == 20)
        {
            zoomRatio = 11.5f;
        }
        else 
        {
            zoomRatio = 11.5f;
        }
    }

    public GMapMarkerImageOverlay(PointLatLng p, float heading, float scaleX, float scaleY, double zoom, Bitmap image)
        : base(p)
    {
        overlayImage = image;
        this.heading = heading;
        this.scaleX = scaleX;
        this.scaleY = scaleY;
        this.zoom = zoom;
        SetZoomRatio();
    }

    internal void SetPosition(PointLatLng position)
    {
        //Position = position;
        //LocalPosition = position;
    }

    public void SetHeading(float h)
    {
        heading = h;
    }

    public void SetZoomLevel(double z)
    {
        zoom = z;
        SetZoomRatio();
        //Util.Log($"Zoom level: {z}");
    }

    public void SetScaleX(float x)
    {
        scaleX = x;
    }

    public void SetScaleY(float y)
    {
        scaleY = y;
    }

    public void SetRatio(float r)
    {
        zoomRatio = r;
    }

    public override void OnRender(Graphics g)
    {
        try
        {                
            var temp = g.Transform;
            g.TranslateTransform(LocalPosition.X, LocalPosition.Y);

            float ratio = (float)zoom / defaultZoomLevel;

            ratio *= zoomRatio;

            g.ScaleTransform(scaleX*ratio, scaleY*ratio);
           
            base.ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.OnMouseOver;
           
            base.ToolTipText = $"Ratio:{ratio}";

            // anti NaN
            try
            {
                g.RotateTransform(heading);
            }
            catch
            {

            }           
        
            var sIcon = overlayImage;
            sIcon = new Bitmap(sIcon, sIcon.Width / 1, sIcon.Height / 1);
            g.DrawImageUnscaled(sIcon, sIcon.Width / -2, sIcon.Height / -2);   

            g.Transform = temp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            //Util.Log(ex);
        }
    }
}
```